# How can i install exchange server 2003?

Tags: exchange-2003

I am new in asp.net, My requirement is how to install Exchange server 2003 service pack2 in system to use the microsoft office outlook web access.

Downloaded Things are:
1.E3SP2ENG.exe
2.Microsoft outlook web access administator tool.

Can any body say what are the procedures i need to do from here.
Help me urgently.

Thanks in Advance..

Regards,
s.venkatesh.

Answer (score 3):

The [Exchange Server Deployment Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125074(EXCHG.65).aspx) has all of the information you need.  I would probably start with the section titled [Installing New Exchange 2003 Servers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123643(EXCHG.65).aspx).

Comment: RTFM ... I like it!